# Sum law of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that the sum law of 2 limits

$$  \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = A \quad \text{and} \quad  \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = B \quad \longrightarrow \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) + g(x) = A+B$$
applies if both A and B are constants, or if one of them is constant and the other it $\pm \infty$,
but what happens if both of them are $\pm \infty$?

Are $(\infty \pm \infty)$ indetermint? In this case is the sum law useless?

Comment: The problem is that, in the real numbers, infinities are merely directional and not actually values.  Therefore, while $\infty + \infty \to \infty$ and $-\infty -\infty \to -\infty$, $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate.  If you were using hyperreal numbers (rare), then you can often make sense of infinite elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $A$ and $B$ are $\infty$ then the implication is still true with $A + B = \infty$.

If however $A = -\infty$ and $B = \infty$ then there is no such theorem. The last limit could be anything or it might not exist in that case. For example:

- If $f(x) = -x + \pi$, $g(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) + g(x) = \pi$.
- If $f(x) = -x$, $g(x) = x^2$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) + g(x) = \infty$
- If $f(x) = -x + \sin x$, $g(x) = x$, then $f(x) + g(x)$ doesn't converge.